# Error: tokens can only be created server-side using the API Secret

Tags: javascript, node.js, client

Its is showing an error

SiteError: This method can only be used server-side using your API Secret, use client = stream.connect(key, secret)

Failed to load resources : the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server error)

```
const stream = require('getstream');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const StreamChat = require('stream-chat').StreamChat;
const crypto = require('crypto');
require('dotenv').config();
const api_key = process.env.STREAM_API_KEY;
const api_secret = process.env.STREAM_API_SECRET;
const app_id = process.env.STREAM_APP_ID;
const signup = async (req, res) => {
try {

    const { fullName, username, password, phoneNumber } = req.body;

    const userId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');

    const serverClient = stream.connect(api_key, api_secret, app_id);

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    const token = serverClient.createUserToken(userId);

    res.status(200).json({ token, fullName, username, userId, hashedPassword, phoneNumber });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
}};

const login = async (req, res) => {
try {
    

    const { username, password } = req.body;
    
    const serverClient = stream.connect(api_key, api_secret, app_id);
    const client = StreamChat.getInstance(api_key, api_secret);
    if (!client.api_secret){
        client.api_secret=process.env.STREAM_API_SECRET
    }

    const { users } = await client.queryUsers({ name: username });

    if(!users.length) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User not found' });

    const success = await bcrypt.compare(password, users[0].hashedPassword);

    const token = serverClient.createUserToken(users[0].id);

    if(success) {
        res.status(200).json({ token, fullName: users[0].fullName, username, userId: users[0].id});
    } else {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Incorrect password' });
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
   } };
   module.exports = { signup, login }
```

[Error while running in server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJGgM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Remove your environment and hard code your `api_key`, `api_secret`, and `api_id` into your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It makes no sense but it worked for me when hardcoded the credentials